# generate a random int given a random bit function

Tags: random, binary, numbers, bit-manipulation, bit

Suppose  you're given a `int randBit()` function which returns, uniformly distributed, 0 or 1.

Write a randNumber(int max) function.

This is my implementation, but I can't prove/disprove that it's right.

```
    // max number of bits
    int i = (int)Math.floor(Math.log(max) / Math.log(2)) + 1;

    int ret = randBit();
    while (i-- > 0) {
        ret = ret << 1 | randBit();
    }

    return ret;
```

The basic idea I had is that

- find the number of bits present in the number
- then generate the number by continuously concatenating the LSB until the bitlength is met

Comment: The approach is reasonable for powers of 2 (or power of 2 minus one: you don't make it clear if `max` is inclusive or exclusive), but think about what happens when the number is not a power of 2. For example, when `max` is say 6.

Comment: If max is 2 I get results between 0 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to fill an int with random bits is the right way in my opinion. However, since your algorithm only works when max is power of 2 and is off by one in the loop, I'd suggest this modification:

```
// max number of bits
int i = (int)Math.floor(Math.log(max) / Math.log(2)) + 1;

int rnd = 0;
int mask = 1;

while (i-- > 0) {
    rnd = rnd << 1 | randBit();
    mask <<= 1;  // or: mask *= 2
}
double q = (double)rnd / mask; // range is [0, 1)
return (int)((max + 1) * q);
```

Let's take a look at this:

`i` will always be equal to the number of bits that `max` occupies. When the loop is finished, `rnd` will contain that number of bits filled randomly with 0 or 1, and `mask-1` will contain that number of bits filled with 1s. So it's safe to assume that the quotient of `rnd` and `mask-1` is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. This multiplied with `max` would wield results in the range between 0 and `max`, also uniformly distributed, in terms of floating/real values.

Now this result has to be mapped to integers, and of course you'd want them also to be uniformly distributed. The only catch here is the 1. If the quotient of `rnd` and `mask-1` is exactly 1, there'd be an edge case that would cause trouble when scaling to the desired result range: There would be `0 .. max-1` values uniformly distributed, but `max` would be a rare exception.

To take care of this condition the quotient has to be built such that it ranges from 0 to 1, but with 1 *exclusive*. This is achieved by `rnd / mask`. This range can be easily mapped to uniformly-spreaded integers `0 .. max` by multiplying with `max+1` and casting to int.

Comment: shouldn't `(double)rnd/mask` yeild [0,1] (1 inclusive) ? Because it's possible that rnd is all 1s

Comment: Please explain how the last (int) conversion is going to produce a uniform distribution (for example in [0,5) given 8 equi-probable combinations of 3 bits 000 to 111)

Comment: @aka.nice In case of `max==4` (3 bits), `(double)rnd/mask` ranges from 0 to 7/8. This multiplied by 5 (max+1) yields `[0/8, 35/8]`. So `rnd` maps as follows: 000..001=>0, 010..011=>1, 100=>2, 101..110=>3, 111=>4.

Comment: @OneTwoThree mask is a power of 2, it's always the maximum rnd value + 1.